# How do I repeat my program based on user's input?

Tags: python

I have created a python program for basic unit conversion.

This is what that I have created:

```
print("\n  -: A Simple Application for Convert Liter(L) to Cubic-centimeter(cc/cm\u00B3) :-")
print('   ',  ("\u207B" * 71))

value = input("\n     Enter the value (in L): ");

if '.' in value:
    try:
        value = float(value)
        print('\n     ==>', value,'L is equal to', value * 1000, 'cc/cm\u00B3.')
        input("\n\n     Thanks for use me :)\n     Hope it helped you!\n     Press 'ENTER' key to exit........")
    except:
        print('\n', "\n  Something went wrong! :(")
        print('\n', "    Exit and Try again! [make sure you'r entering a Integer value or Float Value]")
        input("\n\n     Press 'ENTER' key to exit........")
else:
    try:
        value = int(value)
        print('\n     ==>', value,'L is equal to', value * 1000, 'cc/cm\u00B3.')
        input("\n\n     Thanks for use me :)\n     Hope it helped you!\n     Press 'ENTER' key to exit........")
    except:
        print('\n', "    Something went wrong! :(")
        print('\n', "    Exit and Try again! [make sure you'r entering a Integer Value or Float Value]")
        input("\n\n     Press 'ENTER' key to exit........")
```

Now I want to repeat my program again based on user input.

Basically what I'm trying to do:

1. after showing answer or showing this `print('\n', "    Something went wrong! :(")`; it will asks user for repeat this. If value for yes = y OR Y, It will repeat the program from the beginning.
2. If value for no = n OR N, It will stop after showing output of this `input("\n\n     Thanks for use me :)\n     Press 'ENTER' key to exit........")`.
3. If value is not equal to `'n', 'N'` or `'y', 'Y'` , It will show `Invalid Input!`
4. And above those two condition `(1)` and `(2)` will be inside in both `try` and `except` statement.

Anyone help please??

Comment: The easiest solution would be to wrap your whole program in a loop

Answer (score 0):

```py
print("\n  -: A Simple Application for Convert Liter(L) to Cubic-centimeter(cc/cm\u00B3) :-")
print('   ',  ("\u207B" * 71))


def liter_to_cc(value):
    try:
        if '.' in value:
            value = float(value)
        else:
            value = int(value)
        print('\n     ==>', value,'L is equal to', value * 1000, 'cc/cm\u00B3.')
    except:
        print('\n', "\n  Something went wrong! :(")
        print('\n', "    [make sure you'r entering a Integer value or Float Value]")
        while True:
            again = input("\n\n    Would you like to try again? [y/n]").lower()
            if again == 'y':
                return True
            elif again == 'n':
                return False
            else:
                print('Invalid Input!')


while liter_to_cc(input("\n     Enter the value (in L): ")):
    pass
print("\n\n     Thanks for use me :)\n     Hope it helped you!")
input("\n\n     Press 'ENTER' key to exit........")
```